# Python Requests Can't Get Content

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I created this script that tests authentication keys and returns if the key works or not. But for some reason, I keep getting a 404 error if the script sends it automatically

```
print('Select your key list')
keyfile = easygui.fileopenbox('', 'Select your combo file')
lines = len(open(keyfile).readlines())
while lines > 0:
    with open(keyfile, 'r') as fileforkeys:
         for key in fileforkeys:
         lines -= lines
         url = f'https://api.mullvad.net/www/accounts/{key}'
         r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
         AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36'})
         response = str(r.content)
         print(r.status_code)
         if r.status_code == 200:
             print(Fore.GREEN + f'{key} works!')

         else:
             print(response)
             print(Fore.RED + f'{key} failed!')
```

When I run this code it gets a 404 error and the following response:

```
b'{"code":"ACCOUNT_NOT_FOUND"}'
```

The key does work so this doesn't make any sense. If I change my script to this it works:

```
print('Select your key list')
keyfile = easygui.fileopenbox('', 'Select your combo file')
lines = len(open(keyfile).readlines())
while lines > 0:
    with open(keyfile, 'r') as fileforkeys:
         for key in fileforkeys:
         lines -= lines
         url = 'https://api.mullvad.net/www/accounts/0189605687294417' # actual working key is placed here which makes the script work.
         r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
         AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36'})
         response = str(r.content)
         print(r.status_code)
         if r.status_code == 200:
             print(Fore.GREEN + f'{key} works!')

         else:
             print(response)
             print(Fore.RED + f'{key} failed!')
```

So basically if I insert the key into the script instead of having the script iterate over a text file it works. This makes no sense as it ends up sending the same URL and headers. Why is this happening?

Comment: may be you need to do `key.strip()` before calling the APIs.

Comment: the '0000000000000000' key, don't work, the site returns ```b'{"code":"ACCOUNT_NOT_FOUND"}'``` Do you have a key which works to test?

Comment: Yup tried that. Unforttunatley still doesn't work

Comment: @No.Bo Yes I just added a working key into the script.

Comment: Do the code indent correctly?

Comment: Yes, I had some other meaningless code before this so I just edited the indentation here. It's not an indentation problem

Comment: can you do me a favor, after `url = f'https://api.mullvad.net/www/accounts/{key}'`, can you do a `print(url)` to see what the url is being stored as? I'm suspecting it's possibly taking the key in as a data type `int` instead of a string, and changing `0189605687294417` to `189605687294417`...losing that 0 padding. It's just a guess